# Issues with creating a Facebook App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I have app that sharing photos on Facebook  when I put my Facebook App ID in the project.plist I got the login window but not the allow window and there is no picture posted on Facebook which I think it is related to a mistake in creating the Facebook app.
It is the first time I create a Facebook app and I'm not sure what did I miss, let me explain to you what I did so you may be able to help me :

1- I put the app name and the app NameSpace 
and create the app ID and secret .

2- Disabled the Sandbox Mode.

3- At the (Native iOS App) I added my app Bundle ID, iPhone App Store ID number, enabled the Facebook login and disabled the Deep linking.

4- At the Permissions : I choose Friends for the Default Activity Privacy, added to Users & Friends Permissions : ( email,user_status,publish actions ), 
added to Extended Permissions :( photo_upload ) 
choose the ( Query String…) for the Auth Token Parameter , and enabled the Authenticated Referrals.

5- At the Advanced : I picked the (web) at Authentication with blank (Deauthorize callback URL) , 
*App Restrictions : Age Restrictions (Anyone 13+) and enabled the Social Discovery. 
*Migrations : I only enabled ( Remove offline_acces permission, Explicitly Shared OG Stories and Picture As Dictionary ). 
*Security : all blank and set No for (Set Client Token).

Now as you see, do you think I missed something? or did I do something wrong? 
Do I need to add a website for the (Mobile Site URL) at the (Mobile Web) in the Basic Settings, if so what URL do I need to add ? is it the URL of my App on itunes ? what do I need to do? 
Please I need a help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed all these steps described in  [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)?

Have you add `-sqlite3.0` to your Other link flag?

And then you should not forget to Add the `FBSession` to your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationopenURL:(NSURL *) urlsourceApplication(NSString *)sourceApplicationannotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

And also these code in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // if the app is going away, we close the session object
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    //  (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

Comment: Yes I did , actually I have a sample project with a Facebook App ID which is working fine but when I change it to my Facebook App ID nothing happens. That is what making me assuming that the problem is in the creation of the Facebook App.

Comment: Have you tried your Facebook App ID with other projects? it could be something wrong with your Facebook App ID. I think you can easily create a new project and see if it works or not.

Comment: Have you create a Facebook App before ?

Comment: Yes of course. I followed that video, and then add these code to my AppDelegate. We need to create a new App [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) also, as you know. you need to set URL for your project in xcode to your Facebook App ID. You need to write `fb` before the ID. I made a mistake one time about that, just want to mention.

Comment: Can I suggest you something? if you don't mind. Can you please make a video tutorial about that ? And upload it on YouTube . Thanks .

Comment: The best video is on the link that I sent to you in my answer. I can not do better than them. :)

Comment: Ok, do you think the steps I followed on my question are right? Or did I do mistakes ?

Comment: I think these steps are too much. You could not able to send photo and it is a very simple thing. Have you checked the helloFacebook Sample? I think you should first do the simple things and go to detail step by step.